# Using bootstrapper with MSI ui

Tags: wix

I have MSI file that is ready to install. It contains a customized UI that also collects data from user. As part of installation, i would like to install following things if missing

- .Net framework 4.0
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)

From what I learned, bootstrapper should contain UI as well. How can I use bootstrapper for only initiating prerequisites stage and then proceed with MSI UI installation?

Answer (score 25):

If you use the Visual Studio Setup and Deployment projects bootstrapper (`GenerateBootstrapper` related things) then it will show your MSI UI after installing the prerequisites. It's a pretty simple bootstrapper.

I believe the custom bootstrapper UI you are thinking about is the new Burn functionality in WiX v3.6+. Burn is a lot more powerful and can create single, seamless user experience for multiple chained packages (.exe's or .msi's or .msp's or .msu's). Using Burn you can create a very custom UI that does not show any UI from your chained packages. Alternatively, you can have Burn show the MSI UI. Basically, Burn is highly configurable but does require a bit of extra work (since WiX toolset doesn't provide *everything* out of the box, yet).

To show the MSI UI when running in a Burn-based `Bundle` you'll need to add `DisplayInternalUI='yes'` to the `MsiPackage` elements you want to display. For example:

```
<Chain>
   ...
   <MsiPackage ... DisplayInternalUI='yes' />
</Chain>
```

If you are using the wixstdba (which is very common), it will show it's UI until it comes time to install the .msi package. Then the .msi package UI will pop-up on top and return back to the wixstdba UI to complete the `Bundle` install. You could provide your own Bootstrapper Application if you want to change the way that the Bundle based UI shows up.

Comment: I'm talking about Bootstrapper Project that comes with with WiX toolkit (3.7 in my case). When I create simple test project, it already pops a different ui window.

Comment: Cool, I updated my answer to add more details about showing `MsiPackage` internal UI in a `Bundle`.

Comment: Is there some no-ui default bootstrapper, like the one everybody who doesn't use wix always used or I have to roll my own?

Comment: There is no such BA today. Could be an interesting thing to discuss on the wix-devs mailing list if you were interested in contributing or enhancing wixstdba.

Comment: If I provide my own Bootstrapper Application can I completely hide the Bundle based UI?  So just my MSI UI is shown?

Comment: @Felix, yes. It is possible create a BA that shows no UI itself.