# Remove "Installation successful" Dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm having a problem with the wix installer.
I want to remove the last dialog window when installing my application. The last dialog only shows the message "installation successful" and the user has to click finish.
I want the installation to close automatically after the progress bar reaches 100%.

I tried the approach [Changing the UI sequence of a built-in dialog set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) but i got numerous errors and could not get it to work.
I also tried user "joylons" answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045658/removing-license-dialog) but had no success either.

Is there another way to get this to work? Or can someone help me with the mentioned approach?
I am using the WixUI_Minimal scheme:

```
<UI>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
</UI>
```

**EDIT:**
Based on other answers I tried to use WixUI_Common and alter the sequences.

```
<UI>
      <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TARGETDIR" />
      <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Custom" />

      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title"  FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

      <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />

      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="1"></Publish>
     </UI>
     <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />

      <InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Sequence="1"/>
      </InstallUISequence>

      <AdminUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Sequence="1"/>
      </AdminUISequence>
```

Changes to the InstallUISequence or AdminUISequence do not seem to have any impact. The installer still shows the three dialogs: licence, progress and then the finished dialog. 
I tried to remove the Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" and get the error: "Exit dialog/action not found in 'InstallUISequence' Sequence Table"

**EDIT2:** I changed my UI Tag like this (according to Chris Eelmaa's answer):

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />     
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
  <UI>
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
    </InstallUISequence>
    <AdminUISequence>
      <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
    </AdminUISequence>
  </UI>
```

Unfortunatelly the dialog is still shown at the end of the installation process...

**EDIT3 (25.03.15)**
The problem seems to be the bootstrapper I'm using. Without the bootstrapper Chris Eelmaa's solution works. The bootstrapper seems to ignore all of the changes i make in my .wxs file and still displays the ExitDialog. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy, basically you need to overwrite the scheduled "Show exit dialog when installation was successful", and say that it should never happen. The "0" means disabled.

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
</InstallUISequence>

<AdminUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
</AdminUISequence>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! I tried that, but get the following error messages: "ICE20: UserExit dialog/action not found in 'InstallUISequence' Sequence Table" and "ICE20: UserExit dialog/action not found in 'AdminUISequence' Sequence Table". Any suggestions?

Comment: @Facy87: Ignore what I said. Updated the post.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work. I can build the project without errors, but the dialog is shown again. My UI tag:  

    `<UI>
        <InstallUISequence>
          <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
        </InstallUISequence>
        <AdminUISequence>
          <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
        </AdminUISequence>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/></UI>
      <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />`

Comment: @Facy87: Weird. I tried it myself and it worked. My definition **order** was: 1) WIXUI_InstallDir, 2) UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal", 3) UI InstallUISequence stuff..

Comment: Hmm... I edited my question. The code should be clearer now. I don't know why it is not working. Did you also copy the Code from the WixUI_Minimal source?

Comment: I partially solved the issue now. The problem is the bootstrapper I'm using. Without the bootstrapper your solution works! The bootstrapper seems to ignore all of the changes i make in my .wxs file and still displays the ExitDialog.

Comment: @Facy87: Itś unclear how you show the UI in bootstrapper. See if "DisplayInternalUI" helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805571/using-bootstrapper-with-msi-ui

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa, how did you learn zero means disabled? [Docs](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/show.html) say it supports inner text but not what that does.